# Holding F5 on Wordpress site causes 100% CPU (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, cpu-usage

I am running an instance of Wordpress on an Ubuntu 10.04 VMWare server. If I hold F5 or CMD+R on a page or post, both CPU's on the server will climb to 100%. There will be plenty of free RAM left, but the CPU's will stay at 100% until all the requests have been taken care of. Depending on how long I hold F5, it can take anywhere from a few seconds to process up to a few minutes.

I have disabled persistent connections in MySQL, set the MaxClients section of Apache via a recommended calculation, and disabled all unnecessary plugins within the Wordpress install, yet it still happens (albeit, not nearly as bad as before). Is there anything else I can modify to disallow this from happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Not really...the server's going to process as quickly as possible no matter what.

Comment: You're basically benchmarking your server in the most crude way imaginable. (Actually, your imagination is better than mine. It's never occurred to me to just hold F5.) You should check out Apache [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) or another tool that'll let you simulate more realistic use cases and emit actual data. If you decide you need to make changes to get better perf, you'll be able to measure the effects of your attempts.

Comment: One our users discovered this "benchmark" :)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely caused by PHP processing your scripts. This can be optimized with the use of caching. This can be done with help of wordpress plugins. Some popular ones:

- WP Super Cache http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/
- W3 Total Cache http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

You can find comparison of different plugins here: http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/web-tutorials/wordpress-caching-whats-the-best-caching-plugin/

If you also configure `Varnish` this can give even better results.

More information:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/Caching
- http://jeffreifman.com/detailed-wordpress-guide-for-aws/install-varnish/